# Can I add more than two appsettings.json files in dotnet core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

e.g - appsettings-A.json ,appsettings-B.json ,etc. If yes, how to read these files.
These are not environment based.

Comment: Are you trying to configure multiple environments? Then maybe [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Not different environments, different files for different states (just a example)

Comment: any solution? I'm attempting to use same dll, 2 instances with different json configs

Answer (score 6):

> Can I add more than two appsettings.json files in dotnet core?

> e.g - appsettings-A.json ,appsettings-B.json ,etc. If yes, how to read these files

Of course, we can add and use multiple appsettings.json files in ASP.NET Core project.

To configure and read data from your custom json files, you can refer to the following code snippet.

*In Program.cs, [configure the JSON configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#json-configuration-provider) to load the `appsettings-B.json` file*

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings-B.json",
            optional: true,
            reloadOnChange: true);
    })
    //...
```

*To read data from configurations settings*

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _logger = logger;
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var testkey_val = Configuration["MyTestSection:TestKey"];
    //...
```

*appsettings-B.json file*

```
{
  "MyTestSection": {
    "TestKey": "hello"
  }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: With this approach, how configuration will know which file to read, Like I have appsettings-C.json.

Comment: This does not answer the question IMHO. I believe the OP wants to use two appsettings.json in the same application at the same time. In our case the specific reason is we want the "normal" appsettings.json file to be deployed with the app at all times; however, we have other settings that should only be used in the dev environment and we do NOT want these settings in the normal appsettings.json file so that those values never appear in the appsettings.json file in any publish.